# Надо ставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Человек _ есть организм сложный.

Answer (score 2):

В справочнике Лопатина читаем:

> § 10. Между подлежащим и именным сказуемым **на месте отсутствующей
>   связки** ставится тире, если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены
>   существительными в форме именительного падежа: Флигель у дома на
>   Садовой по проекту Михаила Александровича Врубеля — единственное
>   строение из владений Мамонтовых, почти сохранившее свой внешний вид до
>   наших дней(Кис); Пушкинский край — край камней
>    (Гейч.)

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106

Заметили, что тире ставится **на месте отсутствующей
 связки** ? В Вашем примере имеется связка ЕСТЬ, поэтому нет тире.

Answer (score 0):

Из Правил Русского языка (https://therules.ru/dash/#175):

> § 166.Тире ставится перед *это*, *это есть*, *это значит*, *вот*, если
>   сказуемое, выраженное существительным в именительном падеже или
>   неопределённой формой, присоединяется посредством этих слов к
>   подлежащему, например:
>
> Коммунизм — это есть Советская власть плюс электрификация всей страны
>   (Ленин).

В вашем случае (между подлежащим и сказуемым) тире не ставится:

> Наличие таких небольших, повторяю, недостатков должно приблизить,
>   очеловечить его облик и даже, может быть, вызвать грустную,
>   всепонимающую улыбку: мол, ничего не поделаешь, человек есть человек.
>   [Фазиль Искандер. Мой кумир (1965-1990)]
>
> Если говорить о человеке с современным секуляризованным обывателем, то
>   хорошо начинать с представления о том, что человек есть существо
>   богоустремленное, теоцентрическое. [Иоанн Мейендорф. Православное
>   свидетельство в современном мире (1992)]